# MySQL how to properly deal with rows containing code/cross-site-scripting?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, xss

assuming I parse a logfile that has been submitted by some user and store the parsed data in a MySQL database.

Now if a user is mean enough he could submit a logfile that contains a line similiar to `nickname=<script>alert(hello);<script>`. The parser would grab everything behind the *equals* sign and execute an `INSERT INTO nicknames (name) VALUE ('<script>alert(hello);</script>')`.

I have tried around a bit and figured that `mysqli_real_escape_string()` is preventing a line in logfile such as `nickname=' AND 1 = 2` from breaking the query by escaping the `'`.
I assumed it would also deal with `<script>`/`<`/`>` and other codes/characters, but apparently I was wrong.

In the case mentioned above, when a user submits a logfile containing the line `nickname=<script>alert(hello);<script>`, the `nicknames.name` column will hold the value `<script>alert(hello);<script>`.

Later those values are read from the table and are displayed, one nickname per row in a `<table>` on a website. Ofcourse it won't display the "nickname" in this case; the cross-site-script is being executed. Instead of a table row containing a nickname a message box pops up saying 'hello'.

Is there any common way to prevent cross-site-scripting with a function similiar to `mysqli_real_escape_string()`? What is the *proper solution* to this problem, or maybe even the best?

Ofcourse I could strip off the `<` and `>` before `INSERT`ing into the column, but I would prefer a way that would just display the nickname even with a  `<script>` tag in it, in the table.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) to convert all the html tags syntax to respective entities. this will cause the literal value of `<script>alert('name');</script>` to be displayed rather than being interpreted as a script block